# Save file to host from docker container

Tags: docker

I've an app running inside a linux alpine docker image.

How can I "bind" my host machine directory (EX: /root/my_files) to docker, to make it save the files in my host machine, instead of saving inside docker ( which make me lose all files everytime it rebuilds ).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout docker volumes. It enables you to create a "shared" folder between your host and your Docker container. This way you can create and change folders and files on Docker container and see it on your host, and vice-versa.